# graphics from a class onto a form

Tags: c#, windows, c#-4.0, graphics, picturebox

Okay, so I needed to make a simple animation in c# to use as a loading icon. This worked all fine and good so lets take this square as an example

```
   PictureBox square = new PictureBox();
   Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(square.Width, square.Height);
   Graphics baseImage = Graphics.FromImage(bm);
   baseImage.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 0, 0, 100, 100);
   square.Image = bm;
```

So with that I made my animation and everything here worked, but then I realized that I need my animation to be in a class so I can call it from my co workers programs to use the animation. This is where the problem came in, I made my class and I did everything the same way but in a class instead of the form I then called my class from my form but the screen was blank and there was no animation. Is there something that needs to be passed in order to do this?

```
namespace SpinningLogo
{//Here is the sample of my class
    class test
    {
        public void square()
        {
            PictureBox square = new PictureBox();
            Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(square.Width, square.Height);
            Graphics baseImage = Graphics.FromImage(bm);
            baseImage.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 0, 0, 100, 100);
            square.Image = bm;
        }

    }
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{//Here is how I call my class
    Debug.WriteLine("11");
    test square = new test();
    square.square();
 }
```

Comment: I don't see where you display your `PictureBox`.  Was it "on the form" before as a child control, but now you're not doing that?

Comment: Are you trying to create a new `PictureBox` on the form or write on an existing `PictureBox`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass your `test` class a reference to the `PictureBox` that is on the form:

```
namespace SpinningLogo
{
    class test
    {
        public void square(PictureBox thePB)
        {
            Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(thePB.Width, thePB.Height);
            Graphics baseImage = Graphics.FromImage(bm);
            baseImage.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 0, 0, 100, 100);
            thePB.Image = bm;
        }

    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    test square = new test();
    square.square(myPictureBox);  //whatever the PictureBox is really named
}
```

You could also pass the `Form` itself (using `this`), but then you'd still have to ID the `PictureBox` control (I assume).

Answer (score 0):

You should pass to your test class Form instance, and not define PictureBox in test class. PictureBox should be field of Form, and by Form instance u will get access to your PictureBox.